# What happens when a mini star forms and falls on earth?

Tags: space

Disregarding the fact that we can't create a 'star' on earth, what would happen when a mini star is created on earth with some hocus pocus, technology humanity developed 4 billion years later and Einsteins with a death wish, and [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) strikes and the star goes critical?

The star has a diameter of 10cm

Since it's such a small star, I'm assuming that it's lifespan is pretty much nonexistent and as such would 'die' . However, what would happen in its wake? Would the surroundings be toasted black? Would the gravity crush the surroundings?

Additional little question. What would happen when a star of diameter 10 cm falls to earth from outer space?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "star" in this context. Ordinary stars have to be very large to work at all, even the feeblest have more mass than Jupiter. If you mean an artificial device that fuses hydrogen into helium as a source of power, and owing to amazing technology is only 10cm in diameter, I would hope it would have safety mechanisms to turn it off if it had an accident.

Comment: I mean a conventional celestial star. Let's just say those people never really placed too much thought on what could happen AFTER they made the star. And yes I mean exactly what you said. Thanks!

Comment: Stars are already being made in labs, it is called fusion reaction. They require a lot of safety measures, but in case such a reaction went "uncontrollable" it be just a mini nuclear blast. 10 cm of star (hydrogen plasma) just isn't enough to critically alter gravity or affect the whole planet.

Comment: @Chinu Don't fusion reactions occur in a star and not create a star? Should I make it bigger then?

Comment: @Sky Imagine your question is "what if I made a tennis ball with a diameter of 1 millimeter." The answer would be that a 1 millimeter ball is not a tennis ball, although it has some similar features, such as being round. A "star" as small as you say is not a star. It's just a ball.

Comment: @Ginasius. The "star" is not even a ball. It's a gas cloud, as its gravity isn't sufficient to keep the gas together.

Comment: What is the mass of that thing?

Comment: @Vincent 75kg something, not big.

Comment: @MolbOrg How do you know it's 75kg? At that size it could as well be a neutron star.

Comment: @Vincent at that size it can't be nor start, nor neutron star, [black hole star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) might be. Usual stars, with thermonuclear reactions are higher percentage of other objects we call stars - so I choose them as prototype. I posted answer so you might read why 75kg.

Comment: Without knowing at least the mass and temperature of this mini star, this question is unanswerable since too many assumptions have to be made.  Answers so far all begin with some pretty major assumptions that are vastly differant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the object is something artificial that fuses hydrogen to helium, and is intended as an "extra star in the sky" as seen from the surface of a planet. But someone has dropped it onto the surface, and the question is what harm it does?

Well, to do that, we need some idea of its temperature, and the amount of heat it produces. This isn't actually too hard to estimate.

It's meant to look like a star in the sky, and it's 10cm in diameter. It produces heat by the same means as a star, kind of, and is meant to look like one, so let's give it the same surface temperature and output per unit area.

At this point, it has, however, ceased to be remotely physically plausible, because no material can contain that temperature, and it's far too small to hold itself together by gravity. That requires being the size of a normal star. This ten-centimetre star is considerably less "science-based" than, say, *Star Wars*.

You might be able to fake something up with a black hole, but using black holes to create extra stars in the sky of your planet is an indescribably bad idea on safety grounds. It's the sort of idea where if you propose it with any degree of credibility, you should be immediately arrested, tried, and executed. So I'll assume that isn't how it works.

So, let's say our ten-centimetre star is trying to look like a star that's the same as Alpha Centauri A. Its diameter is 0.1 metres, rather than about 10^9 metres, so to be as bright as ACA, it needs to be at about 1/10^10 of the distance, which is about 450 kilometres, or 280 miles. So it can be in orbit around the planet, but you don't want to go anywhere too close to it, because its temperature is about 6,000 Kelvin, and it's emitting about 4 megawatts of light and heat.

Now some fool has dropped it onto the surface of Earth. Anything flammable nearby catches fire. All sorts of things will burn when hot enough, so it will reach bedrock reasonably soon. That won't burn, but it will melt. Everything will melt at these temperatures, and almost everything will boil away into gas - tungsten might stay liquid. So it tunnels down until the shaft above it closes over it firmly enough to hold the gas pressure of vaporised rock and the rock ceases to be able to boil away.

At this point, the density of this device becomes crucially important. I have no way to predict what that might be, because it isn't remotely physically plausible. The crucial numbers, in grams per cubic centimetre, are about 2, about 3, and about 8. If its density is less than 2, it will float in whatever rock it melts now that it can't boil, and will be pretty much stable there. That's good, although a density so low seems unlikely. If its density is less than 3, it will melt its way downwards until it finds a dense rock, and then float in that. If its density is more than about 8, it will continue melting downwards until either the pressure breaks it in some way, or it reaches the centre of the Earth. Having it there is actually fairly harmless, because its heat output is negligible on the scale of the Earth's core.

However, if the idiot who dropped it did so in a volcanic area, it may well start an eruption as it melts its way downwards. Doing this in an area of active volcanism, like the [Yellowstone Caldera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowstone_Caldera) is a really bad idea, unless you really want to cause a large-scale disaster, rather than the localised one you get in a non-volcanic area.

Edit: How long can it burn for? Well, that's not reliably answerable, because we don't know its mass. It also isn't performing either [P-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) or [CNO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) fusion, because those require temperatures of several million Kelvins, and are very slow. Really very slow indeed. Human tissue at rest generates heat at about four times the rate of an equal volume of the Sun's core. Honestly! The Sun is so hot because it's very, very large and the square-cube law means that its surface area -- while vast by our standards -- is very small in comparison to its stupendous volume.

In fact, there's no way to generate power continuously inside the mini-star via fusion and have its surface temperature be so low. However, if we interpret the description rather creatively, we can claim that it's actually the end of a wormhole to the surface of a nearby star, which only allows radiation through and not matter. This is actually one of the more plausible ways of building it, for very loose definitions of "plausible".

Would @Sky care to change the tags on this question? "Science-based" really doesn't describe it.

Comment: Nice answer.  How long could the "star" last. At 4 megawatts, and fusing 4H -> He, is it going to last hours, days or years?

Comment: Edited an answer to that in.

Comment: "If its density is less than 2" — less than 2 *what*? 2 kg/m³? 2 g/cm³? 2 times the average density of earth? 2 Planck densities?

Comment: Edited an answer to that in, too.

Answer (score 4):

*The star has a diameter of 10cm*

### Nothing

For both of your question, nothing, nothing super fancy will happen, at all.

Density of our sun, in [its core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core) is 0.150kg/cm<sup>3</sup> (it is place where actually energy is produced, and reactions are reacted)

so this object will have mass something like 75kg - no gravitational effects.

As reaction, main reaction is [Proton–proton chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) and some [CNO cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle). For more dense object CNO could be more active, for our sun main reaction is proton–proton.

Energy output for our sun is 276.5 W/m3 - because reaction are very slow, it is a problem to fuse H+H.

So with stellar properties of such object - nothing fancy, and it can't exists outside device in which it is created, or without that device.

### Bit of fancy

As object 75kg, with temperature 15e6 K, and pressure 26.5 PPa (26.5e15 Pa) - it have not bad potential for destruction.
Based on [Effects of nuclear explosions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions#Summary_of_the_effects), I would estimate it something starting with 20+kt blast (based on pressure, 1bar sphere of that ball will change pressure from 26.5 PPa to 100kPa by growing to 650m radius sphere.)

Probably it will be more then 20kt, my second guess something like 40kt.
This are rough guesses, because for such dense material pressure drops nonlinear(so it is upper estimation).

As Ideal gas - 15kk K energy of 75kg H, corresponds to $\small \sim$2kt.

But anyway, it seems to me not likely it to be a super megablast.

### Fancy stuff

Blasting device which creates that tiny sun, will be fancy, or exposing that tiny star, being near it when it works, will be fun.

With 15kk K it emits 8.625e+19 W, with its 0.1m diameter and 15kk K temperature. It is equivalent to 20Gt blast each second, this is noticeable amount of energy, compared to our sun it is 1/4'400'000 of sun total energy.

So if it will enter a planet when it works, it might have noticeable effects on planet scale.

As weapon of mass destruction,  like 2 end blackhole, where one end is somewhere in the star, and exit hole like hose showering target have potential, have chance to destroy even pretty advanced ships if they have no unobtanium stuff.

Showering not necessary means eruption of mass, it might be like arc, so we return that mass back to sun(at surface as example) with second hose, but it is constantly exposed at some point outside sun.

So in some cases, fancy stuff can happen, for both your questions, but not because it's star like, but because noticeably energy, although dyson swarm could do better but limited with distance and ability to focus energy. And they are different by spectrum, this star arc will emit gamma-rays mostly, so penetration will be better.

Answer (score 1):

### Nothing

Your hocus pocus made this in space. Fine. As soon as the magic stops gluing it together real physics will take over (that’s sort of what the question wants to know). Pressure will make it expand to the density of the upper atmosphere. It has so much heat it literally won’t be able to fall, the hot plasma will stay high over us and each dispersed atom will share its (very large) energy with the molecules it hits.

There will only be a ka-boom if your magic shell is like out thermonuclear weapons. Even an H-bomb has to carry its own hydrogen fuel for fusion because once the shell is cracked, it’s too “cold” to fuse airborn hydrogen. But if you release the magic shell from space, you will get a miniature Starfish Prime light show over the clouds. If you decide to hold the ball together longer, then gravity can work on it. Then, when it hits the ground, you might get a bigger bang like the other answers offer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along [these lines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J2bP9glb-w).

A star is a fusion explosion that — normally — is so big that it takes billions of years to finish.

In your case however, it is so small that it will burn out instantly and make a mushroom cloud. And that is about it. You just re-invented the [hydrogen bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon).

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to compare a star to a nuclear bomb. The mechanisms are different - ranging from confinement (in a star, that's gravity, and so it's well-controlled) and the exact details of fusion.